# Fix initramfs with command won't boot can't use recovery

Tags: initramfs

I am trying to  find out how to get my Ubuntu 15.10 to boot. I've messed up somewhere and I have no access to the ISO so need to figure out the command to boot into Ubuntu again. I can agree grub 2 but still no idea how to fix.

Comment: Do you get Grub menu? Is Ubuntu the only OS on computer?

Comment: I can use grub and yeah it's the only os now

Comment: I'm not sure actually I can use grub command line

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try this: start the computer; while the BIOS loads, hold Shift key until a menu appears (GRUB). Select "Advanced options...", then select an entry which contains "recovery mode" at the end (must be second in the list). Wait until another menu appears. Select "network". When it finishes, select "dpkg". Wait until it's done. Then select "resume boot". See if this works.

Comment: I tried that and it says nonblocking pool is initialized. Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning

Comment: Then after doing that for a while it goes to busy box initramfs

Comment: What happens if you type 'exit' in BusyBox?